# log in for android studio adafruit MQTT not working

Tags: android-studio, mqtt, adafruit

I am trying to use Leonardo Cavagnis' app he developed for using MQTT on android phones.

Find it here:  https://medium.com/swlh/android-and-mqtt-a-simple-guide-cb0cbba1931c

I have opened it in Android studio and although it works using the sign in for HiveMQ I tried to sign into my Adafruit account using  tcp://io.adafruit.com/1883 with my client name, client password and client Key as the client id.

It tries to connect but after a bit it says that the client id is invalid.  Can anyone look at this and give me a suggestion where to look to modify this so it works with Adafruit.

Comment: I'm sorry but this type of question really isn't well suited for Stack Overflow. You are expected to do try and debug this yourself, we won't go download a random project from the internet and debug it for you. I suggest you approach Leonardo directly for support with his application, if he can't/won't help then you will need to try and debug this yourself and you can ask specific technical questions if you get stuck.

Comment: But I suggest you double check the client details from the docs https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-io/mqtt-api